# Java: Why can't I call methods returned from myArrayList.get()?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
for(int i=0;i<this.count();i++)
{
    System.out.println(mediaRegister.get(i).getTitle());
}
```

`this.count` simply returns the length of `mediaRegister`. `mediaRegister` is an arraylist containing objects. All those objects have a title field, which should be gettable by object.title, or in this case object.getTitle() which is a method which simply returns the String 'title'.

Why can't I call the objects methods and fields by mediaRegister.get(i).method()? Compiler tells me 'the method is undefined for the type Object'.

If more code is needed, I'll happily abide.

PS: Might it have something to do with the fact that mediaRegister is a generic ArrayList (i.e. I haven't beforehand specified which type it will contain)? They're a new concept for me so I'm probably breaking all the ArrayList etiquette rules in the world.

```
public MediaReg()
{
    mediaRegister = new ArrayList();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> PS: Might it have something to do with the fact that mediaRegister is a generic ArrayList (i.e. I haven't beforehand specified which type it will contain)?

Yes, that's exactly right. You should be using generics. You haven't told us the type of element you're actually putting in the list, but if it's something like `MediaItem`, you'd have:

```
// Name of class expanded for readability.
public class MediaRegistry
{
    private final List<MediaItem> items;
    ...

    public MediaRegistry()
    {
        items = new ArrayList<MediaItem>();
    }
}
```

At that point, the compiler will know that `items.get(x)` returns a value of type `MediaItem`, so you'll be able to call any methods declared in `MediaItem`, etc.

If that's all you need to do in the constructor, you could just move the initialization to the field declaration:

```
public class MediaRegistry
{
    private final List<MediaItem> items = new ArrayList<MediaItem>();
    ...
}
```

In Java 7 you can use the "diamond syntax" to make this more concise:

```
public class MediaRegistry
{
    private final List<MediaItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

See the [Java Generics Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for more information about generics.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Generics - see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for a good tutorial.

Without specifying the type of things in mediaRegister the compiler has to assume that they're the most basic things i.e. `Object`. By defining mediaRegister as a generic arraylist you can tell the compiler that it contains things with certain fields and methods i.e. by writing

```
ArrayList<MyType> mediaRegister = new ArrayList<MyType>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The type is undefined because the declaration type.The compiler unable to detect the type returning `get(i)` because of your `declaration type`.

```
ArrayList<MediaRegister>  mediaRegister = new ArrayList<MediaRegister>();
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases when you can't modify original collection or you should integrate with legacy code, it helps just to cast fetched object explicitly to desired type:

```
for(int i=0;i<this.count();i++) {
   System.out.println( ( (MediaRegister)mediaRegister.get(i) ).getTitle() );
}
```

Comment: BTW, it's a bad practice to iterate through list collection using get method. You should use iterator instead or just 'for each' cycle.